# Using Jcrop form an ajax loaded image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image-uploading

I have a site where I would like to upload a profile picture to the server and store the image into the database, using ajax. This is pretty straight forward and does work. But I would like to be able to get the user to be able to to crop their image so that it is square using Jcrop. I have seen and downloaded examples of how to implement Jcrop, which are pretty straight foreword. But I just can't seen to get it to work on my site. The code I have so far is rough and still needs a bit of validation but I want to get the main function dealt with first.
To make the cropping process seem a little more user friendly I have created a basic light-box type thing to hold the upload form and then the image to crop after sent back from php. This seems to be the only difference form what I've seen online.

Here's my code:(*I have just picked out the relevant parts as the site contains quite a lot of text and images in other divs that aren't relevant*)
HTML IMPORTS:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
```

HTML: - form to upload a new Profile Pic

```
<div id="reg_pp">
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="100%" height="150px" /><br/><button id="updateGender" style="float:right; width:auto;" class="form_fields_button" onclick="changeProfilePic('open')">Change Profile Picture</button>
            </div>
```

HTML: - lightbox type thing

```
<div id="ppuo" class="overlay">
    <div id="ppufh" class="tcs">
        <div id="close_btn" onclick="changeProfilePic('close')"></div>
        <div id="nppf">
            <div id="preview"><img src="assests/preview.png" width="150px" height="150px" id="thumb" /></div>
            <form id="uploadPP" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input id="image" name="image" type="file" class="form_fields" size="20" style="width:100%" />
                <input type="hidden" id="user" name="user" value="session_generated_id"/>
                <div id="npp_err_msg"></div>
                <input type="button" id="changePPBtn" value="preview" onclick="check()"  />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript: -toggle profile picture change dialog/lightbox

```
function changeProfilePic(toggle){
    var overlay = document.getElementById('ppuo');
    var content = document.getElementById('ppufh');
    if(toggle === 'open'){
        //display overlay
        $('#ppuo').fadeIn({complete:function(){}},500);
    }else{
        //hide display
        $('#ppuo').fadeOut({complete:function(){}},500);
    }
}
```

JavaScript: - upload image and start of JCrop

```
function check(){
    var formData = new FormData($('#uploadPP')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'global.func/upLoadPP.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function(){
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){
                //myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        data: formData,
        //Ajax events
        //beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: function(data){
            var return_type = data.substr(0,1);
            var data_type = data.split(":");
            if(parseInt(data_type[0]) === 4 || data_type[0] === '4'){
                //no error
                $('#ppufh').animate({width:'800px',height:'80%',marginTop:'10%'},500);
                document.getElementById('thumb').src = data_type[1];
                document.getElementById('thumb').style.width = '80%';
                document.getElementById('thumb').style.height = 'auto';
                document.getElementById('ppufh').style.overflow = 'scroll';

                        $('#thumb').JCrop({
                        aspectRatio: 1,
                        onChange: updateCoords,
                        onSelect: updateCoords,
                        bgColor: 'blue',
                        bgOpacity: .5,
                        sideHandles:false,
                        minSize: [ 50, 50 ]
                    });

                document.getElementById('changePPBtn').value = 'Finished Cropping';
                $('#changePPBtn').on('click',function(){
                    window.alert("save new profile pic");
                });
            }else{
                var err_msg = data_type[1];
                document.getElementById('npp_err_msg').innerHTML = '<h3 style="text-align:left">'+data+'</h2>';
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("There has been an internal server error. Please try again.");
        },

        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

PHP: -in case it helps but does work fine as a basic start

```
<?php

include '../constant/connect.php';
$row_count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile_pics"));
if(isset($_POST)){
    $user_email = $_POST['user'];
    $file = $_FILES['image'];
    if($_FILES['image']['error'] > 0){
        echo '0:php server error adjust php.ini file, then change this error message.';
    }else{
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $extention = explode('.',$file_name);
        $extention = $extention[1];
        if($extention == 'jpeg' || $extention == 'png' || $extention == 'gif'){
            $path = '../images/user_profile_pictures';
            $new_file_name = md5($file_name.$row_count).".".$extention;
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../images/user_profile_pictures/" . $new_file_name);
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO profile_pics (pp_src,pp_owner) VALUES ('".$path."/".$new_file_name."','$user_email')")or die(mysql_error());
             echo '4:images/user_profile_pictures/'.$new_file_name;
        }else{
            echo '1:Wrong type of file, use jpg, jpeg, png or gif. No animated Gifs.';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'data not passed';
}
?>
```

It looks like it should work but there may be something I have missed and can't spot that somebody else can. So if anybody can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
getElementById('thumb').style.height = 'auto';
                document.getElementById('ppufh').style.overflow = 'scroll';

                        $('#thumb').JCrop({
                        aspectRatio: 1,
                        onChange: updateCoords,
                        onSelect: updateCoords,
                        bgColor: 'blue',
                        bgOpacity: .5,
                        sideHandles:false,
                        minSize: [ 50, 50 ]
                    });

                document.getElementById('changePPBtn').value = 'Finished Cropping';
                $('#changePPBtn').on('click',function(){
                    window.alert("save new profile pic");
                });
            }else{
                var err_msg = data_type[1];
                document.getElementById('npp_err_msg').innerHTML = '<h3 style="text-align:left">'+data+'</h2>';
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("There has been an internal
```